# How to make table to scroll with an Android device?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I am using a jQuery Mobile script and datatables and I must say that I have successfully combined those two together.
But here is a problem that I have noticed. When I am testing my application with an Iphone I am able to perform an inner scroll of the table with 2 finger gestures sliding up/down, but when I tried on several Android devices inner scroll of the table is not working.

My table has a hide/show option so when I am in the last line where results are shown and when I press plus button an additional window is opened but I can't scroll down and with an Iphone I can. What could I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a script for this as otherwise your phone OS do not know if you want to scroll the inner div or the whole page :

This is the one and only : http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4